# How to set color of extra image space in BoxFit.cover mode?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, i have PageView with List of Images inside.
I don't understand how to set color between thighs images in extra space that happened because cover

```
Container(
   child: PageView(
      children: List.generate(
                   widget.product.images.length,
                   (index) => Image(
                                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                                 image: NetworkImage(widget.product.images[index]),
```

Changing color in Container does not give any effect. How can i do this?

Example - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQORY.png)

Comment: Does removing `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` remove the extra space?

Comment: @JoyTerence no((

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Image widget inside a Container widget.

The PageView is going to take all the width of parent widget (i.e. Page) and that's the reason you won't see any background color you set at parent Container.

The List is also taking the entire width of the PageView. So to have a color between images, you will have to wrap the the Image into Container. Also, set the container width to double.infinity.

```
Container(
 child: PageView(
  children: List.generate(
               widget.product.images.length,
               (index) => Container(width: double.infinity, color: Colors.red, child: Image(
                             fit: BoxFit.cover,
                             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                             height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                             image: 
  NetworkImage(widget.product.images[index]),),
```